# stsClass objects inside array

Tags: arrays, stdclass, control-structure

I `var_dumped` a variable and got this, how can i show it properly?

Like,
`<p> Name: <?php echo $Firstname.' '.$Lastname; ?>

     Country: <?php echo $country; ?></p>`

```
 <?php
 array(3) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { 
                                    ["Firstname"]=> string(4) "John"
                                    ["Lastname"]=> string(4) "Lest"
                                    ["Country"]=> string(3) "USA" 
                                    }
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#20 (3) {
                                    ["Firstname"]=> string(5) "Larry" 
                                    ["Lastname"]=> string(4) "Jems" 
                                    ["Country"]=> string(6) "Canada" 
                                    } 
        [2]=> object(stdClass)#21 (3) { 
                                    ["Firstname"]=> string(3) "Jim"
                                    ["Lastname"]=> string(5) "Ricks" 
                                    ["Country"]=> string(7) "England" 
                                    }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdClass` is (kind of) an anonymous object. Firstname, Lastname and Country are properties. To access them:

```
echo $obj->Firstname
```

Comment: stdClass objects are inside an array, when i `echo $results[0]->$obj->$Firstname; `, it says undefined variable, actually i need to loop through all those objects.

Comment: @NestedWeb: try `echo $results[0]->Firstname`. If you can't get the loop to work from there, you should really go back and re-read the PHP manual.

Comment: @NestedWeb `$obj` was just an example since you did not provide the actual variable name.